# Passing Data to ViewModel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm

I’m new to MVVM pattern so please don’t judge me. What I want to do is that I want to pass the data with the segue if it is possible to the ViewModel and populate the data based on that. Why I want to do so, because imagine I have 3 ViewControllers (A, B, C). On A ViewController I’m getting the Data from Realm Database and then I’m passing around those data with the segues and I really don’t want to change that structure. However if you will have better suggestion, please let me know as well.

Here is my code:

```
//MARK:- ViewModelItemTypes
enum EventViewModelItemType {
    case description
    case materials
}

//MARK:- ViewModel

class EventViewModel: NSObject {
    var items = [EventViewModelItem]()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let confEvent = ConferenceEvents()
        let confMaterials = EventMaterials()

        if let descriptionText = confEvent.eventDescription {
            let descriptionItem = EventViewModelDescItem(descriptionText: descriptionText)
            items.append(descriptionItem)
        }

        if let materials: EventMaterials = confMaterials {
            let materialsItem = EventViewModeMaterialsItem(materials: [materials])
            items.append(materialsItem)
        }
    }
}

extension EventViewModel: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items[section].rowCount
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        switch item.type {
        case .description:
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.confEventDescriptionCell, for: indexPath) as? ConfEventDescTCell {
                cell.item = item
                return cell
            }
        case .materials:
            if let item = item as? EventViewModeMaterialsItem, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.confEventMaterialCell, for: indexPath) as? ConfEventMatTCell {
                let materials = item.materials[indexPath.row]
                cell.material = materials
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return items[section].sectionTitle
    }
}

//MARK:- ViewModelItem Protocol
protocol EventViewModelItem {
    var type: EventViewModelItemType { get }
    var rowCount: Int { get }
    var sectionTitle: String { get }
}

extension EventViewModelItem {
    var rowCount: Int {
        return 1
    }
}

//MARK:- View Model Items
class EventViewModelDescItem: EventViewModelItem {
    var type: EventViewModelItemType {
        return .description
    }

    var sectionTitle: String {
        return "Description"
    }

    var descriptionText: String

    init(descriptionText: String) {
        self.descriptionText = descriptionText
    }
}

class EventViewModeMaterialsItem: EventViewModelItem {
    var type: EventViewModelItemType {
        return .materials
    }
    var sectionTitle: String {
        return "Materials"
    }
    var rowCount: Int {
        return materials.count
    }
    var materials: [EventMaterials]

    init(materials: [EventMaterials]) {
        self.materials = materials
    }
}
```

As you can see I have empty instances of confEvent and confMaterials. They are my models and I’m using RealmSwift. **My suggestion is to populate those models with the data, but I don’t know how to do so. And that’s where I want you guys to help me.**

Here is my ViewController Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var viewModel = EventViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 70
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.dataSource = viewModel
        tableView?.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.register(ConfEventDescTCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.confEventDescriptionCell)
        tableView.register(ConfEventMatTCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.confEventMaterialCell)

    }
}
```

**UITableViewCells:**
First UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class ConfEventDescTCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!

    var item: EventViewModelItem? {
        didSet {
            configureUI()
        }
    }

    private func configureUI() {
        guard let item = item as? EventViewModelDescItem else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.descriptionTextView.text = item.descriptionText
        }
    }

    static var nib:UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

Second UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class ConfEventMatTCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var matTitle: UIImageView!

    var material: EventMaterials? {
        didSet {
            guard let material = material else { return }
            configureUI()

        }
    }

    private func configureUI() {
        guard let material = material else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.matTitle.text = material.materialTitle
        }
    }

    static var nib: UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your `viewModel` into `ConfEventDescTCell` where it is created.

So for instance in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you would create a new UITableViewCell and then pass the viewmodel instance into it using a method call or as a property or some other way. The problem is that there are a bunch of ways to do this.

The key is that before you show the cell, you retrieve information from the specific viewmodel to customize it.

**Update:** I think it's best to not have empty models in your viewmodel. There should be no models there at all. The better solution may be to generalize the way you are getting the data and then get it in the viewcontroller where you actually need it. There you would then directly create the correct viewmodel for the views you have there.

Comment: If you see the code I’m doing exactly as you are saying :). However my Question is different: Right now it retrieves nil, because there are no data in the ViewModel (specifically in confEvent or in confMaterials). So I want to somehow get the data on the viewModel

Comment: I only see you registering the NIBs. Your ViewController code is a bit on the short side.